# ion-select doesn't show the content when clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

`Update:` This is not working on mobile view. You can change that on the browser and set it as `galaxy s5`. After setting the device viewport you need to refresh the browser. i.e. `f5`

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rt2iwm)

Inside the form I have this:

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-select formControlName="title" required item-start>
        <ion-option value="1">Mr.</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="2">Mrs.</ion-option>
     </ion-select>
     <ion-label floating>{{'full-name' | translate}}</ion-label>
     <ion-input formControlName="fullName" type="text" required></ion-input>
            <img src="assets/imgs/icon_user.png" class="icon_user" item-end />
  </ion-item>
```

But it doesn't show the dropdown when I clicked it. But if I remove this (i.e. `ion-input`) control then I can see the dropdown. i.e. `<ion-input formControlName="fullName" type="text" required></ion-input>`

`Note:` I can see both controls on the form like so.

[image]

*.ts*

```
initForm() {
    this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['1', Validators.required],
      fullName: ['', Validators.required],

    });
  }
```

Do you know why this behavior?

Comment: there is no problem with your code check https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dzngms

Comment: Remove it from `ion-item`. It will work

Comment: It is not working on mobile view. You can change that on the browser and set it as `galaxy s5` @FatemeFazli

Comment: i set it to galaxy s5 and it works, i think the problem is somewhere else, when you click the select the input triggers, try to put some margins between them and test.

Comment: Your example is also not working. After setting the device viewport you need to refresh the browser. i.e. `f5` @FatemeFazli

Comment: Looks like a bug in Ionic to me. Guess you'll have to open an issue at their repository...